# dolphinscheduler3.1.4 masterserver.log too bigger

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

dolphinscheduler-master.log

```
[ERROR] 2023-04-07 06:32:36.794 +0000 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.WorkflowExecuteRunnable:[1015] - [WorkflowInstance-31][TaskInstance-0] - Submit standby task ods_to_dim error, taskCode: 9106041001504
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
[ERROR] 2023-04-07 06:32:36.794 +0000 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.WorkflowExecuteRunnable:[1015] - [WorkflowInstance-27][TaskInstance-0] - Submit standby task ods_to_dim error, taskCode: 9106041001504
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
[ERROR] 2023-04-07 06:32:36.794 +0000 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.WorkflowExecuteRunnable:[704] - [WorkflowInstance-0][TaskInstance-0] - Start workflow error
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.WorkflowExecuteRunnable.submitStandByTask(WorkflowExecuteRunnable.java:1847)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.WorkflowExecuteRunnable.submitPostNode(WorkflowExecuteRunnable.java:1362)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.WorkflowExecuteRunnable.call(WorkflowExecuteRunnable.java:698)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeuQW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5ov1.png)

dolphinscheduler-master.log is to bigger